# `org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification` without parsing the complex query

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, filter, spring-data-jpa

in the Spring Boot api i'm developing, the query filter is coming in ready from the client so as to go into the `where` clause of the
jpa (or rather, sql) queries to be made via repository.

Eg. suppose that there's a `Book` entity with fields `title`, `author`, `edition`.
All the `Book`-s will be queried with a filter `String` like

```
String str = "title = 'cooking' or 'recipes' and edition > 5";
```

this clause can directly be fed in to the where clause as follows:

```
select *
from book
where title = 'cooking' or 'recipes' and edition > 5 ;
```

the question is, how to create the `org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification` directly from this query filter String? Can a -- can a `Specification` instance be created from from `str` without having to parse/process it in any way?

i'll do pagination on the results. so, an explicit call on `EntityManager` of jpa won't do. it's gotta be on the repository.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

How about use JPA NamedQuery?
U can declare in repository interface.

your example query can be coverted to

```
Page<Book> findAllByTitleInAndEditionGraterThan(List<String> titleList, int editionNo, Pageable pageable);
```

[Check this link, description about JPA named query](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

Comment: query is dynamic-- comes in at runtime and can be of any form. this nowhere near fits the bill

Comment: then how about use QueryDSL? I think it can solve your problem.

Comment: @Query isn't dynamically bound either

Comment: QueryDSL is kinda plugin for dynamic query via JPA style. U need to add dependency but I'm pretty sure it can be helpful your question.

Answer (score 0):

> can a Specification instance be created from from str without having to parse/process it in any way?

No, there isn't.
And it would be a really bad idea to do something like that.

1. From a design point of view you introduce extremely strong coupling between your frontend and the persistence layer. Very bad idea.
2. From a security point of view you are basically describing assembling a SQL statement by string concatenation, which opens up SQL injection vulnerabilities. Very, very bad idea.

Comment: not sure what i'd do-- probably the same as it's done if i were to design it. would sure consider the feasibility of an sql-content checker/verifier-- sql's been around since forever by now so are its query parsers. right now though, i sure would take that free ride on Specification. different set of concerns on a prototype. some things should be left to developers' choice.